# cron и несколько одновременных заданий

Tags: linux, cron

Если я поставлю в cron две задачи на исполнение в одно и тоже время, то как они будут запущены на выполнение (и выполняться): параллельно или поочередно (вторая выполнится после первой)?

Comment: будут паралельно

Comment: @Mike, т.е., если я хочу их выполнить последовательно, то нужно  набросать простой скрипт и поставить его на выполнение? Правильно? Или есть другие варианты?

Comment: @Mike И еще вопрос тогда... Если задача, поставленная в cron (например, ежеминутно) не успевает выполниться, а уже подошел срок повторной постановки, то запустится второй ее экземпляр или все-таки cron дождется окончания работы первого?

Comment: Ну если параметров не особо много вы можете и несколько задач написать прямо в крон `задача1 параметры && задача2 параметры`. Правда в этом случае задача 2 выполнится после успешного выполнения первой. Можно попробовать в принципе через точку с запятой в одной строке, мне кажется должно и так работать. Если задача не завершилась крон запустит ее второй раз. Поэтому задача должна сама контролировать что ее копии сейчас нет (паример опять же скриптом, который положит свой PID в /var/run и при запуске проверит а нет ли там файла и задачи с таким PID

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Оформляйте ответ, если не лень :)

Comment: посмотрел, нашел у себя запуск через точку с запятой, да, подалуй запилю ответ :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если задачи описаны в crontab в разных строках то они будут выполнятся независимо друг от друга, в том числе и параллельно, при совпадении времени.

Если надо, что бы две задачи выполнились строго друг за другом то можно написать их в одну строку, разделив точкой с запятой:

```
01 12 * * * mike task1 parameters; task2 parameters; ...
```

Кроме того, если к времени своего следующего старта предыдущий экземпляр задачи еще не завершился, крон не будет ничего проверять и запустит вторую копию. Отслеживание параллельного запуска и препятствование этому остается на совести самой выполняемой задачи.